# I want to simply make a script for send "arrow right" in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to simply make a script for send "2x arrow right" in autohotkeys. I now have:

```
^Tab::
 Send, 
 return
```

After Send, I tried several combinations, some of them being {right}, {Right}, plus over 10 more combinations I found on the net which supposed to perform the difficult task of arrow right, but none which managed to work. Only thing I want is to Send, [insert some words which will do the trick] to have autohotkeys perform "2x arrow right". Would make my life a lot easier during programming. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

No need for `Return` for single-line statements. Keys can be repeated as so:

```
^Tab::SendInput {Right 2}
```

See more about *repeating* keys with `Send[Raw|Input|Play|Event]` and about using `SendInput` *instead* of `Send` here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail

Answer (score 1):

Switched from `Send` to `SendInput` for reliability.

The easiest way to solve this would just be to make your script send two `SendInput, {right}` one after another.

For Example:

```
^Tab:: 
SendInput, {right}
SendInput, {right}
return
```

If you needed it to loop a finite number of times, you could use this instead:

```
^Tab:: 
Loop 2 ;replace '2' with however many times you want the next line to repeat
    SendInput, {right}
return
```

---

Sidenote: In the context that I am using it, return just means to stop executing a multi-line hotkey. What your example above does is send the word "return". If you want to send a special key like the right arrow button or the return/enter key, you would have to enclose it in curly braces `{}`. For example, `{right}` or `{return}` corresponding to the aforementioned examples. For more information about this, please see [this documentation link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames).

Comment: Hi Spyre, thank you so much for your quick answer!

Now, before trying out what you mentioned in your post, I quickly want to respond to your sidenotes.
The "send" and "return" lines actually had to be on seperate newlines, but for some reason Stackoverflow doesnt translate the newlines I posted in my code to the actual topic :(
I meant:


^Tab::   /newline

 Send, /newline

 return 

If that makes sense. Sorry for this. Would you know how stackoverflow actually accepts my newlines instead of putting it all in one line?

Comment: @Neoking Here is a tip for getting the code to format properly. Whenever you need to insert code into your question or response, enclose your code with triple backticks [```]. Alternatively, just highlight what you want to be displayed as code and click the Code Sample Button at the top of your question/ answer input box (alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+k). Link to this and more formatting info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. -*Also, if this solution solved your problem, could you please mark it as the solution to this question? *Thank you!-