# Is the `return` statement necessary at the end of an AHK script?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

My one-line script:

```
Shift::Send ^{Space}
```

Is it necessary to add a [`return`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) statement like the following?

```
Shift::Send ^{Space}

return
```

Comment: An answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191976/i-want-to-simply-make-a-script-for-send-arrow-right-in-autohotkey  says it isn't necessary -- but there isn't an exact duplicate

Comment: @user202729 Could you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68840493/7881859) as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote an example from the [`return`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm#Examples) documentation to demonstrate what it does:

> The first Return separates the hotkey from the subroutine below. If it were not present, pressing the hotkey would cause `Sleep 1000` to be executed twice.
>
> ```
> #z::
> MsgBox The Win-Z hotkey was pressed.
> Gosub MySubroutine
> return
>
> MySubroutine:
> Sleep 1000
> return
> ```

Also, quote from [Hotkeys Introduction and Simple Examples](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro):

> If a hotkey needs to execute only a single line, that line can be listed to the right of the double-colon. In other words, the `return` is implicit:
>
> ```
> #n::Run Notepad
> ```

As a side note, if binding multiple hotkeys to the same action, we can write:

```
#a::
#b::MsgBox
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a subroutine with a label like you show above, the subroutine will be called and will continue until it gets to either return or exit.

So in this example, return isn't necessary

With functions, return is actually assumed in ahk so you don't necessarily need to include it unless your passing it with an expression.

In either case though, you might want to include it just to make things more readable.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68840493/7881859) as well?

Comment: I think this answer is awfully bloated with confusing information. The answer is simply that one liner hotkey definitions don't need a `return`, as stated in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro). And I strongly disagree that adding in an useless return makes it more readable, on the contrary, in my opinion.